# How to determine if two points lie in a particular section of circle.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

I'll take assistance from the figure below.
[image] O is the center of the circle, and A,B,C are the points on the circle, and are known. i.e. the x,y coordinates of these three points are known. I want to know, that for the center point O, and any other point, say `a,b,c` [small characters], if O and that particular point is in the same region.

To add to the assumption, let us say, AB and the other line are horizontal or vertical. i.e. parallel to the X and Y axis.

Also, what if I remove this assumption?

Thanks.

**EDIT** I guess, for the given assumption, I could just check if the other point (not the center) has the x and y coordinates, in range of the A B and C, towards the side of center. That is, if center has coordinate value more for A and not for B and not for C, then so should the other point? Will that be correct?
What if the assumption is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just calculate which side of $AB$ the point is on.  If $AB$ is horizontal, you just check the $y$ coordinate of the point.  If $AB$ is not horizontal, you have the line AB as $y-y_A=\frac {y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}(x-x_A)$  A point is above the line if the left side is greater than the right.

The line through $C$ you check the same way.  If it is vertical, just check the $x$ coordinate.  If it is not, there is nothing to specify its slope and you need to fix that, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Basically, slant or straight, what I can do is, for each point, that is on the boundary of the circle, I can actually check it's relative position to the center, that is for A, if x is less than O's x coordinate, and y is greater than O's then it should be the same for any other point, in that region, similarly, for B and C. right?

Comment: ^ I dont think that will work for the slant lines, also the problem is that I do not know the other coordinate from C.

Comment: @Kraken:  for a slant AB it works fine.  Compute $y-y_A-\frac {y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}(x-x_A)$ for the center of the circle and the other point.  If they are the same sign, they are on the same side of the line.  For a slant line from C, you need to define the line.  Currently it can slide along AB without restriction unless the line from C is perpendicular to AB.  In that case, you can find the point of intersection and use the same procedure.